# How to connect 6 LCD 16x2 to a Raspberry Pi 3?

Tags: i2c, screen, lcd

I need help with this project. I want to connect SIX LCD 16x2 screens to my Pi and send different messages between the screens. I was wondering if I could use I2C but there is a problem with the personal address 0x27 is the same for each screen.

[image: LCD_16x2]

Do you know how I can change the address?
Or another appropriate way to connect them?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If its one of the standard i2c 16x2 controllers it should have 3 pairs of address pads labelled A0,A1,A2. Jumping these according to the table below changes the i2c address.

[image]

[image]

http://www.ardumotive.com/i2clcden.html